# How to initialize an output in verilog?

Tags: initialization, verilog, quartus

I have been trying to initialize my output LEDR [3:0] to all 0. However, LEDR keeps being XXXX in my waveform timing diagram. I have tried using initial block, but it doesn't work. (My IDE is Quartus Prime)

Here is my code

```
module synasyn_counter(SW,LEDR,PLoad,CLK);
    parameter n=16;
    input CLK,PLoad;
    input [3:0] SW;
    output reg [3:0] LEDR;
    initial 
    begin
        LEDR=0;
    end
    always @(negedge PLoad or negedge CLK)
    begin
        if (PLoad==0) LEDR<=SW;
        else 
        begin
            if (LEDR==n-1) LEDR<=0;
            else LEDR<=LEDR+1;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

And this is my result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use an `initial` block in synthesized code. That is meant to be a purely simulation based code.

In hardware, we generally achieve a flop/register initialization through a `reset` signal. So if you have an active low asynchronous reset in your design, you can do something like this for your flop equation -

```
always @ (posedge clock or negedge reset) begin
  if(!reset) begin
    LEDR <= <initialized_value>
  end
  else begin
    <rest_of_your_code>
  end
end
```

After you have done this, in your TB ensure that at the start you are asserting the `reset` signal (since its active low asserting would mean to pull it down to 0) and then de-asserting it after 1 or more clock cycles.

Please note that, before the `reset` is asserted you will still see an `X` unless the `reset` is asserted from t=0. So after you follow one `reset` assertion-deassertion sequence, you can proceed with the rest of your simulations after that

Comment: As a blanket statement, this is wrong. `initial` values _are_ synthesizable on some hardware, such as [Xilinx FPGAs](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Welcome-Join/are-initial-values-synthesizable/td-p/314923). This also doesn't actually answer the OP's question, which includes a screenshot showing that the code is running in simulation anyway.